# Android device is not picking up new version application automatically even though auto-update is set

Tags: android, auto-update

My customer has created an Android application which is now loaded into Google Play Private Channel. A new version of the application was then created and the Devices that use this application were all set to auto-update and connect even on broadband.

The devices are not picking up the new version of the application even after waiting for 5 days (I'm told 24 hours should be enough time to wait). However, when the user on the device goes to the Google Play Private Channel they're able to see and download the application.

Do you have any idea what they can do to ensure auto-update does its magic and that the application updates with minimal user action?

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: Have any new permissions been added in the new update, if permissions have changed then auto update is temporarily disabled for that upgrade. Once manually upgraded though, if another new version is released without any permission changes then the auto update should work

Comment: Thanks for the information Boardy. I will update the question as soon as I find out if new permissions have been added.